# rename multiple values to have same name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, rename

Here is an idea of what my current table looks like:[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soKue.png)

> 

| date | store | liquor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 | #3 | apple schnapps |
| 2012-01-01 | #3 | peach schnapps |
| 2012-02-15 | #3 | canadian whisky |
| 2012-01-01 | #4 | scotch whisky |
| 2012-01-05 | #4 | tennessee whisky |
| 2012-02-15 | #4 | tequila |

> 

I want to shorten the names of the liquors to names like 'schnapps' or 'whisky'. In my actual table I have thousands of rows with different types of liquors, some with names that I won't shorten. Eventually I will combine rows with similar dates but first I want to simplify the types of liquor. Is there a reasonable way to rename the values with SQL that doesn't require an unreasonable amount of code?

Comment: Can you try and remake the table I'm not able to read it in its current format

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn I think that should look better

Comment: Yes thank you, I believe your best option would be to have a separate table with all the current names in one column and in a separate column the names you want to normalize them too. Then you can just make a join

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to remove the characters before a space would be the query below:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, ' ') + 1) AS subject
FROM  table
```

So if the value is canadian whisky it would return whisky.